# Vaadin server side heartbeats

Tags: java, vaadin

In a vaadin application, I know that the client side javascript sends heartbeats to the server and I can configure the interval by adding following to the web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>heartbeatInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>5</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I think the server also sends heartbeats to the client side because if the server hits a breakpoint and waits for some time on the breakpoint, client side shows that the session expired.

Is it possible to specify a different heartbeat interval for the server to client heartbeats, compared to the heartbeat interval of client to server heartbeats?

Also, [documentation](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Cleaning+up+resources+in+an+UI) says that server will close a UI if 3 heartbeats are missed. Is it possible to change this maximum heartbeat miss count?

(One might think that the same effect of increasing max heartbeat count can be achieved by increasing the heartbeat interval. But, I use the client heartbeats for some other purpose in my application, so increasing the heartbeat interval is not an option for me)

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin actually don't send request from server to client unless you enable server push described [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html).
However, you should consider below to have a stable session and stable UI context. From Vaadin [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-environment.html):

> The session timeout should be longer than the heartbeat interval or
>   otherwise sessions are closed before the heartbeat can keep them
>   alive. As the session expiration leaves the UIs in a state where they
>   assume that the session still exists, this would cause an Out Of Sync
>   error notification in the browser.
>
> However, having a shorter heartbeat interval than the session timeout,
>   which is the normal case, prevents the sessions from expiring. If the
>   closeIdleSessions parameter for the servlet is enabled (disabled by
>   default), Vaadin closes the UIs and the session after the time
>   specified in the session-timeout parameter expires after the last
>   non-heartbeat request.

Comment: Did you find this helpful?